# MapBox Reverse Geocoding Without Map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-api-geocoding

I'm attempting to retrieve places info using the MapBoox JS API.

I currently have forward geocoding working well without a map and now looking to do the reverse.

The docs and other information I've gathered seems to suggest that the two are essentially the same, but the big difference being how the results are returned.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    const latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.mycode';
        var reverseGeocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
        id : 'myid',
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        location: [latitude, longitude],
        callback: 'callback',
        types: 'country,region,place,postcode,locality,neighborhood',
        reverseGeocode: true
    });

    function callback(pos, result) {
        console.log(pos, result);
    }

});
```

Forgive me if the callback is just totally wrong, but this is how I thought it should work. With no direct example in the API doc I wasn't sure what arguments or how many should or could be passed but it made sense to follow the `reverseQuery()`.

I found the `reverseGeocode` argument/option from GitHub issue/commit on reverse Geocoding example.

There are no errors in console but as the docs suggest this functions return is not useful. I don't know how to use the callback as the doc suggest to retrieve information from the result.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to use Mapbox's reverse geocoding service is to call the API directly:

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#reverse-geocoding

You could do that using a library such as axios:

```js
axios.get('https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/-73.989,40.733.json?access_token=YOURTOKEN')
.then(({data}) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess I wanted to know why my attempt is not working. I'm confused why it's not also applicable. If forward coding is done this way, why not reverse? My thinking about this is also due to the forwarding example in the docs presents the forward method of geocoding much like this, and not accessing the API directly.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Forward geocoding is exactly the use case supported by the control: user types in address, find it on the map. Reverse geocoding (start with a lat/long, find a nearby address) isn't something that fits that use case, so tbh, I'm not really sure why you would expect it to work, or what you would expect to happen.

Comment: I guess you could say, you answered my question with that. Simple as I just wanted to know from someone with experience the thinking behind the method, that's all.